# proof verification for converting sentence into propositional logic

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Hi I wanted to know if I have translated this sentence correctly,

The sentence is;

```
If the two propositions a and b have the same truth values, then c is
true; otherwise c is equal to a.
```

So this is the formula I have come with

```
((a ⇔ b) ⇒c) v (c ⇔ a)
```

The word otherwise in the sentence is throwing me off, as I am not sure how to translate it. But I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: "otherwise" means that a and b do *not* have the same truth values.

Comment: I would render "If $p$, then $q$, otherwise $r$" as:$$(p\to q)\land(\neg p\to r).$$

Comment: @BrianO Sorry could you clarify that to me please? because then P and Q would not hold the same value as per first part of the sentence?

Comment: Oh come on: you're supposed to substitute things to preserve the form. $p$ would be $(a\leftrightarrow b)$, and $q, r$ would be other, non-atomic parts of your sentence. Should I give an answer?

Comment: Equivalently, "if $p$ then $q$ otherwise $r$" can be rendered $(p\land q)\lor (\neg p\land r)$ which is closer to your attempt.

Comment: @BrianO oh right sorry, I get you now

Comment: Good, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Wiki answer to close this.

> The word otherwise in the sentence is throwing me off, as I am not sure how to translate it. But I would appreciate some guidance.

It means you are dealing with an "exclusive or" situation.

- "If *this*, then *that*, otherwise *another*" = "If *this*, then *that*, else-if not *this*, then *another*."

$$\Big(\big((a\to b)\wedge(b\to a)\big)\to c\Big)\vee\Big(\big((a\wedge\neg b)\vee(\neg a\vee b)\big)\to \big((a\to c)\wedge(c\to a)\big)\Big)$$

Or in shortened form $\Big(\big(a\leftrightarrow b\big)\to c\Big)\vee\Big(\neg(a\leftrightarrow b)\to\big(c\leftrightarrow a\big)\Big)$

Of course this can be *greatly* simplified to a *much* more concise statement.

> That is: $~T~$.   It is a tautology.   Can you show it?